# Insert string into cell with only integers while keeping fonts- VBA

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, insert, character

I am trying to append text into an excel cell with VBA. Currently I am using :

`Range("A1").Characters(Len(Range("A1")) + 1).Insert ("text")`

This works fine for cells with text, but if the cell contains only numbers (integers) it throws an error:

`Run-time error '1004' Insert method of Characters class failed`

Parts of the text in the cell are in different fonts or bolded and I need to keep them that way.

I have also tried to change the NumberFormat the cell to general, but it does not help:

`Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"`

If someone knows a way to append text to a cell containing only integers with different fonts please answer.

Comment: You could precede your call with `Range("A1").Value = "'" & Range("A1").Value` assuming that there isn't already formatting applied to individual digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Strings, Cells that contain actual Numbers (but not strings that look like numbers) *cannot* have format applied individual characters.

Therefore split your processing based on data type<sup>1</sup>

```vb
Dim cell as Range
Dim AppendText as String
AppendText = "text"
Set cell = Range("A1")
If TypeName(cell.Value2) <> "String" Then
    cell.Value2 = cell.Value2 & AppendText
Else
    cell.Characters(Len(cell.Value2) + 1).Insert AppendText
End If
```

After this has run, cells thar were numeric will now be strings, and *can* have individual characters formmated.

Notes:

1. You might want to consider other data types too: boolean, date, ...